# How bagging on CART (RPART) is different from CART with cross validation?

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, bagging

I am wondering is there any difference between the following two algorithms:

1. RPART (Recursive partitioning) in R, with cross-validation (xval = 10, default)
2. Bagging on RPART

In the first case, Rpart uses 10-fold cross-validation on the original dataframe

In the second, randomly select data from the original dataframe and then perform RPART.

To me both the algorithms look same.

Where am I wrong in my understanding?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Bagging, boosting, and random forests that have recursive partitioning as the estimator result in a prediction tool that is no longer a tree.  That is why these methods have superior predictive accuracy when compared to a single (almost always arbitrary) tree.  Recursive partitioning that incorporates cross-validation still results in a tree.  In many cases, in order to make the tree cross-validate you have to make it so conservative that it is not competitive with other methods in terms of $R^2$.

Comment: thanks for your insight. What I understand now that the method is same but the output is different.  Also, does the bagging algorithm select the whole dataframe for doing RPART or only a fraction of it?

Comment: I'm not sure how to answer that question, but you could say that the methods are not the same but one of the underlying methods is.